# How to learn about print options keys from pycups?

Tags: python, cups, pycups

Via trial and error and looking into the ppd I wrote script below that allows you to print on different trays. I found the correct names for value and key of the job-options in the ppd.

Just by looking into `conn.getPrinterAttributes(printer)['media-source-supported']` those options do not became clear.

I feel like there must be a way how you can get all the possible job options in a better fashion than just looking them up in the ppd file, but I fail to find any documentation on this problem and because the underlying base is in C, I am also a bit unsure how the connection between python and C works there.

In order to better understand how to use pycups and maybe also how the connection between python and C works here, I decided to ask on stackoverflow.

### I have ...

#### Following pycups

Followed `pip show pycups` but only found the `cupshelpers` and pycups info i.e.

> This is a set of Python bindings for the libcups library from CUPS project.

But I didn't find the exact bindings only:

```
cups.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
cupsext.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
cupshelpers/
cupshelpers-1.0-py3.10.egg-info
pycups-2.0.1.egg-info
```

### Program for reference

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import cups

def list_printers():
    conn = cups.Connection()
    printers = conn.getPrinters()

    print("Available printers:")
    for printer in printers:
        print(f"Printer: {printer}")
        print("Supported options:")
        options = conn.getPrinterAttributes(printer)['media-source-supported']
        for option in options:
            cleaned_option = ''.join(c for c in option if c.isalnum()).upper()
            print(f"  {cleaned_option}")
        print()


def print_document(printer_name, document_path, tray_option):
    conn = cups.Connection()
    printers = conn.getPrinters()

    if printer_name not in printers:
        print(f"Printer '{printer_name}' not found.")
        return

    job_options = {
        'InputSlot': tray_option,
    }
    print(job_options)

    with open(document_path, 'rb') as document:
        print_job_id = conn.printFile(printer_name, document_path, "Print Job", job_options)
        print(f"Document '{document_path}' sent to '{printer_name}' with Job ID: {print_job_id}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Specify the printer name, document paths, and tray options
    printer_name = "Kyocera-ECOSYS-P3055dn-KPDL"

    document1_path = "Tray1.pdf"
    document2_path = "Tray2.pdf"

    options = ["PF430A", "PF430B"]

    for option in options:
        print_document(printer_name, f"{option}.pdf", option)
```

Comment: I would like to tell you there is a definitive answer to this, but in fact there is not.  Printing has always had this kind of problem, both on Linux and Windows.  Your path of looking in the PPD is the successful path.

Comment: @TimRoberts but print dialogs are often able to get such information. Do they really parse the ppd files?

Comment: Yes.  Print dialogs are provided by the operating system and make vast assumptions.